# Unidentified ng-controller issue in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I'm trying some initial stuff to get used to AngularJS. My current source is SoloLearn. I tried to recreate their app, which adds +1 to a counter when a button is clicked.

I have tried checking the code from their app, and I've also copied and pasted their work onto my HTML file and it still doesn't work, I tried [an online tool for ascii diffs](https://www.quickdiff.com/) and my code should be identical, yet my inspector yields this:

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=clickCounter
at angular.js:38
at angular.js:10839
at ba (angular.js:9931)
at n (angular.js:9701)
at g (angular.js:9055)
at g (angular.js:9058)
at g (angular.js:9058)
at angular.js:8920
at angular.js:1919
at m.$eval (angular.js:18161)
```

I checked the [site](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/docs/error/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=clickCounter) and as I understand, my code should still be working, yet it's not.

My code:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="count=count+1">Click me!</button>
    <p> {{count}} </p>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('MyApp',[])
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.count=0;
    });
</script>
```

Their code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="clickCounter">
        <button ng-click="count=count+1">Click me!</button>
        <p>{{ count }}</p>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('clickCounter', function($scope) {
        $scope.count = 0;
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your page is still referencing "clickCounter" as the value of the ng-controller attribute.  Are you viewing an older, cached version of your HTML page or something? Try hitting CTRL-F5 (or equivalent).

Comment: I have refreshed many times and in many ways (F5, clicking the button, exited the tab and reopened the file). Should I try deleting my cache?

Comment: I have tried deleting the `div`s I had above this code (they don't use ng-controllers or anything similar) and it's still not working, whereas in a different file with solely their code, it works. That's making matters more confusing.

Comment: You need to structure it so that your `ng-controller` is either on the same element as - or a child element of - the element containing `ng-app`. I would also specifically refer to the app just as a matter of habit using `ng-app="todoApp"`.

Comment: So the HTML attribute should only refer to this app? We can't have multiple apps in the same page? I'm trying to understand, sorry if the question is silly.

Comment: AngularJS will only automatically bootstrap the first `ng-app` directive it finds on a page. You can manually bootstrap additional apps, but I don't think it's considered a best practice. Remember, AngularJS was created as a SPA framework so it really doesn't make sense to have multiple apps. If you are doing it as a way to segment your code you should instead probably just multiple modules that you inject into one master module so that you can have a single `ng-app` directive on your page.

Comment: Oh that explains it then! Thanks! I'll try to learn more, better practices for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lex mentioned, I needed to define the Angular app specifically for the app I was running and not have it all generically crammed in the same place. 
The code on the first URL I posted is working now. Basically changing the `body` tag to this: `<body ng-app="">` and naming each div app made everything work as should. 
Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have added both in different plunker, both are working

http://plnkr.co/edit/Pk8bY3jMiRqwiyWhxEkn?p=preview

http://plnkr.co/edit/aJZTXMQ1dATZI4XUSCmc?p=preview

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="clickCounter">
    <button ng-click="count=count+1">Click me!</button>
    <p>{{ count }}</p>
```

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('clickCounter', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
});
```

Comment: I understand why it would work in any case, I fail to see what's wrong with my effort. Maybe it's a chrome setting?

Comment: if its still not working can you try to setup in a plunker or share entire file

Comment: Edited my question - I shared the file via GitHub, if that's okay. I can set up a plunker or anything else if it's required. Thank you!

Comment: shared github file is also working. may be you should delete cache(ctrl+shift+delete) and restart your browser again.